# Use a Map in a Map or an object

Tags: java, optimization

I've a Map like this

This class used as key

```
class Key {
    private final String type;
    private final String qualifier;
    // getters, equals and hashCode
}
```

The map is `HashMap<Key, Object>`

I dont know if a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>` can be a better option or not.
(In this case the map be like a relation of
keyType -> {keyQualifier -> value, otherQualifier -> value})

Please leave examples

Comment: Kindly post some more info about what are trying to achieve by storing object as HashMap's value. It is based on your requirements only. If you want another key value combination inside of map, you may use JSONObject too.

Comment: no creating a class  `key` for map as you have done is the better option, rather then complicating stuff in values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your attempt is good. It's probably a bit faster faster (just one get() call) and more readable to access an object with your key object than.

```
// Complex key object
Map<Key,Object> map;
Object value = map.get(new Key(type, qualifier));

// 'Simple' key object, don't do this
Map<String, Map<String, Object> map;
Map<String, object> tmpMap = map.get(type); // that is actually confusing to read
Object value = tmpMap.get(qualifier));
```

But don't forget, hashCode() and equals() must be implemented correctly!